# How to prevent download of files to unauthenticated users

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, formsauthentication

I have a website into which users log in using forms authentication, with a folder path from which I do not want any unauthenticated users (those users not logged in) to download files from.  How can I implement this?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: are you using form authentication to authenticate registered users?

Comment: Check this other question to see if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903292/how-do-i-protect-static-files-with-asp-net-form-auhentication-on-iis-7-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this through configuration, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t.aspx

```
<location path="Files">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Yes, but I tend to use IISExpress now when developing locally instead of Casini which was a bit limited. See  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can make function to download (on server side) where you will check current login and then send path to file for accessible people.

Here you can see another ways [get-files-if-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310774/how-to-stop-user-not-get-files-if-not-login)

Answer (score 0):

Place the file in  an authorised folder. so that if unauthorised users come to that folder. they will be redirected to login page to get authorised.